# Failed compile libpvm-rs https://github.com/cadets/libpvm-rs.git

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to compile this library but it failed.

```
mkdir -p build
git clone https://github.com/cadets/libpvm-rs.git
cd build/libpvm-rs && git submodule update --init
cd build/libpvm-rs/build && cmake .. && make
```

I got these errors:

```
 Compiling libpvm v0.1.0 (/home/master1/project/build/libpvm-rs)
warning: use of deprecated item 'std::error::Error::description': use the Display impl or to_string()
  --> modules/pvm-views/src/lib.rs:43:29
   |
43 |             description(err.description())
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

error: failed to run custom build command for `libpvm v0.1.0 (/home/master1/project/build/libpvm-rs)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/master1/project/build/libpvm-rs/target/release/build/libpvm-8cb0935b153c2819/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 1', /rustc/436494b8f8008b600d64b3951f63c2bb0ea81673/src/libcore/slice/mod.rs:2854:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

CMakeFiles/libpvm_target.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'libpvm.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libpvm.so] Error 101
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/libpvm_target.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libpvm_target.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that there is a conflict in library versions. I'm a newbie to Rust  so I can't fix these errors.

Comment: Have you tried to `export RUST_BACKTRACE=1` before calling `make`?

Comment: I did it but i can't understand the stack backtrace. It involve the std, core, cbindgen!

Comment: @Jmb we will need the rust nightly version in order to be able to compile libpvm, so any helps please?

Comment: Well, if you don't show us the backtrace it will be very difficult to interpret it…